# Destinations aren't ordered by ascending. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'am pulling destinations from the database and trying to order them alphabetically in the following way:

```
$destinations = get_posts( array(
                            'post_type' => 'destination_showcase',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'destination_state',
                                    'value' => ':"'.$state_id . '";' , // looking for serialized value in quotes
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            ),
                            'orderby' => 'title',
                            'order'   => 'ASC',
                        ) );
```

but did not succeed. Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$destinations = get_posts( array(
                            'post_type' => 'destination_showcase',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'orderby' => 'title',
                            'order'   => 'ASC',
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'destination_state',
                                    'value' => ':"'.$state_id . '";' , // looking for serialized value in quotes
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            ),

                        ) );
```

try the order change

Comment: They're still not ordered bro :(